# Limiting Cypher queries

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher

I am currently using a neo4j database with 50000 nodes and 2 million relationships to perform cypher `MATCH` queries, like the one below:

```
start startnode = node(42660), endnode = node(30561)
match startnode-[r*1..3]->endnode
return r;
```

This query by itself provides 443 rows, but I only want Cypher to find 5 matches and return those only. Allow me to clarify: **I do not just want Cypher to return only 5 results, I also want cypher to STOP querying once it finds 5 results. I DO NOT want Cypher to get all 443 results.**

Is this currently possible using the `LIMIT` clause? Or would the `LIMIT` wait for all 443 results to be found, then only return the first 5?

**EDIT**: Will the `LIMIT` clause find only the first few results for a complex query like this?

```
start graphnode = node(1), startnode = node(42660), endnode = node(30561)
match startnode<-[:CONTAINS]-graphnode-[:CONTAINS]->endnode
with startnode, endnode
match startnode-[r1*1..1]->endnode
with r1, startnode, endnode
limit 30
match startnode-[r2*2..2]->endnode
with r1, r2, startnode, endnode
limit 30
match startnode-[r3*3..3]->endnode
with r1, r2, r3, startnode, endnode
limit 30
return r1,r2,r3;
```

Here is the `profile` for the query:

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["  UNNAMED216", "endnode", "r1", "startnode", "r2", "r3"],   returnItemNames=["r1", "r2", "r3"], _rows=30, _db_hits=0)
==> Slice(limit="Literal(30)", _rows=30, _db_hits=0)
==>   PatternMatch(g="(startnode)-['  UNNAMED216']-(endnode)", _rows=30, _db_hits=0)
==>     ColumnFilter(symKeys=["endnode", "  UNNAMED140", "r1", "startnode", "r2"], returnItemNames=["r1", "r2", "startnode", "endnode"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>       Slice(limit="Literal(30)", _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>         PatternMatch(g="(startnode)-['  UNNAMED140']-(endnode)", _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>           ColumnFilter(symKeys=["startnode", "endnode", "  UNNAMED68", "r1"], returnItemNames=["r1", "startnode", "endnode"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>             Slice(limit="Literal(30)", _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>               PatternMatch(g="(startnode)-['  UNNAMED68']-(endnode)", _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>                 NodeById(name="Literal(List(30561))", identifier="endnode", _rows=1, _db_hits=1)
==>                   NodeById(name="Literal(List(42660))", identifier="startnode", _rows=1, _db_hits=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing, but in this case, if you were to add `limit 5` after `return`, it would be able to lazily return and skip the rest of the matches. If you were to want to sort, or aggregate, it wouldn't be able to do that for you. If you find this to not be the behavior, please report it as an issue on github (along with the version you're using, etc.)

*update for new query*

```
start graphnode = node(1), startnode = node(42660), endnode = node(30561)
match startnode<-[:CONTAINS]-graphnode-[:CONTAINS]->endnode // do you need this, or is it always going to be true?
with startnode, endnode                                     // ditto. take it out if it doesn't need to be here.
match startnode-[r1*1..1]->endnode // this can probably be simplified to just startnode-[r1]->endnode
with r1, startnode, endnode 
limit 30 // limit to the first 30 it finds in the previous match (this should be lazy)
match startnode-[r2*2..2]->endnode // finds 2 levels deep
with r1, r2, startnode, endnode
limit 30 // limit to the first 30 it finds in the previous match (this should be lazy)
match startnode-[r3*3..3]->endnode
return r1,r2,r3 // the last with you had was extraneous, return will function the same way
limit 30;
```

So, I assume you're asking a question because this query is slow. Might I ask why you're breaking it up this way, instead of just `startnode-[r*1..3]->endnode`, and `limit 30`? Do you really need the first match/with, or is that check unnecessary? Can you provide the output of `PROFILE`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the normal behavior. I tried this with the a complex query `start graphnode = node(1), startnode= node(42660), endnode = node(30561) match startnode<-[:CONTAINS]-graphnode-[:CONTAINS]->endnode with startnode, endnode match startnode-[r1*1..1]->endnode with r1, startnode, endnode limit 30 match startnode-[r2*2..2]->endnode with r1, r2, startnode, endnode limit 30 match startnode-[r3*3..3]->endnode with r1, r2, r3, startnode, endnode limit 30 return r1,r2,r3;`. It took a minute to get results, despite all the limits.

Comment: I have put that complex query in my question for easier readability.

Comment: I am breaking up the query because I later intend to put in parameters for the limits. For example, I want to be able to set the limit to 30 for the whole list of paths, and reduce the limit at each tier. (If `1..1` produces 1 path, then I want the limit for `2..2` to be 29). Also, I have removed the first match/with; that check was unnecessary. However, I am still running into performance issues. I will add a `profile` output ASAP.

Comment: I also tried extending the query to `4..4`, but I end up with no results and what might be a GC dump. This is what I found in the logs:
`GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 14813ms [total block time: 182.589s]`

Comment: The way they'll return is a cartesian product, so reducing the limit as you describe might not have the desired effect (a bunch of repeated r1's for the different r2's, etc.). I have a feeling it's churning on the longer paths, struggling to find 30. Are you running 1.9GA or a milestone release? The default GC settings in GA were improved over M05 and earlier, which should prevent a 15 second freeze like that.

Comment: I am running the 2.0.0 M03 release. Actually, the freeze never stops as far as I'm concerned; the threads were blocked for 10 minutes before I stopped the neo4j webadmin with `./neo4j stop`

Comment: Since you have a start and end node, it has to branch out to try to find the other node at that specific depth. There's no good way to optimize that search, you basically just have to go 4 deep until you happen to hit the other node 30 times. We're talking billions of possibilities depending on your branching factor. If you really need to do this query, you might consider trying an unmanaged extension where you're lower level and have more control.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'll work on a different query then. Thanks for the help though Wes! +1 + Accept

Comment: If you need help with an extension for it post a new question or throw me a message on twitter @wefreema.

Comment: Thank you, I have posted a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607393/extensions-for-computationally-intensive-cypher-queries.